# Is there a way to find the SQL that updated a particular field at a particular time?

Tags: teradata

Let's assume that I know when a particular database record was updated.  I know that somewhere exists a history of all SQL that's executed, perhaps only accessible by a DBA.  If I could access this history, I could SELECT from it where the query text is `LIKE '%fieldname%'`.  While this would pretty much pull up any transactional query containing the field name I am looking for, it's a great start, especially if I can filter the recordset down to a particular date/time range.

I've discovered the `dbc.DBQLogTbl` view, but it doesn't appear to work as I expect.  Is there another view that contains the information I am looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the level of database query logging (DBQL) that has been enabled by the DBA. 
Some DBA's may elect not to detailed information for tactical queries so it is best to consult with your DBA team to understand what is being captured. You can also query the DBC.DBQLRules to determine what level of logging has been enabled.

The following data dictionary objects will be of particular interest to your question:

- **DBC.QryLog** contains the details about the query with respect to the user, session, application, type of statement, CPU, IO, and other fields associated with a particular query.
- **DBC.QryLogSQL** contains the SQL statements. If a SQL statement is exceeds a certain length it is split across multiple rows which is denoted by a column in this table. If you join this to the main Query Log table care must be taken if you are aggregating and metrics in the Query Log table. Although more often then not if your are joining the Query Log table to the SQL table you are not doing any aggregation.
- **DBC.QryLogObjects** contains the objects used by a particular query and how they were used. This includes tables, columns, and indexes referenced by a particular query.

These tables can be joined together in DBC via `QueryID` and `ProcID`. There are a few other tables that capture information about the queries but are beyond the scope of this particular question. You can find out about those in the Teradata Manuals.

Check with your DBA team to determine the level of logging being done and where they historical DBQL data is retained. Often DBQL data is moved nightly to a historical database and there often is a ten minute delay in data being flushed from cache to the DBC tables. Your DBA team can tell you where to find historical DBQL data.

Comment: Could you answer more clearly: which table specifically would contain this info "if logging has been enabled" ?

Comment: Do the revisions help clarify your uncertainty